# Difference between parallel engine and server engine

Tags: etl, datastage

Here is the info from the official IBM web site

[image: Here is the image and description from the official IBM site]

> **> WebSphere DataStage and WebSphere QualityStage server engine**
>
> The server engine runs WebSphere DataStage server jobs and performs
>   some tasks for parallel jobs and WebSphere QualityStage jobs.
>
> **> Parallel engine**
>
> The parallel engine runs parallel jobs and WebSphere QualityStage
>   jobs.

Could please anyone explain what is the actual difference between those two? Is it hardware/software/architecture? Don't get the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short they are two completely different products that are made to look mostly alike in the common client.

Server engine is the old single-threaded(?) engine with limited out-of-the-box stages, insufficient performance and very limited updatability. You should encounter server jobs only in legacy installations that are not performace critical. Everyone else has already upgraded either to Enterprise edition with Parallel jobs or another product.

Enterprise edition of Datastage also contains the Parallel engine which gets all the cool new toys such as SCD-stage, Web Service integration and ability to scale out performance by adding new processing nodes.

You use the same client to develop jobs for each engine and some of the stages may look same but it's superficial.